# How can I use Entity Framework in dependency injection without using Repository and UoW patterns?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, ninject

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application with C#, .NET Framework 4.7, Ninject 3.2.2.0 and Entity Framework 6.1.3.

I'm trying to implement Unit of work and Repository patterns to use it with Ninject to inject them into ASP.NET MVC Controllers.

My problem here is that I'm not sure if I have used correctly the Unit of Work pattern.

This is my interface for the Generic Pattern:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity>
{
    IUnitOfWork GetContext();

    TEntity GetById(long id);

    IQueryable<TEntity> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();

    void Edit(TEntity entity);

    void Insert(TEntity entity);

    [ ... ]
}
```

The interface for the Unit of Work Pattern:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
}
```

And the implementation of Generic Pattern:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    private DbContext _context;

    public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _context = (DbContext)unitOfWork;
        _dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public GenericRepository()
    {
    }

    public IUnitOfWork GetContext()
    {
        return (IUnitOfWork)_context;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbSet;
    }

    public TEntity GetById(long id)
    {
        return _dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public void Edit(TEntity entity)
    {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    [ ... ]
}
```

And Unit Of Work Pattern:

```
public class TRZFDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public TRZFDbContext()
        : base("name=TRZFDbContext")
    {}

    public TRZFDbContext(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AggregationChildrenConfiguration());
        [ ... ]
    }
}
```

Finally, this is a piece of the `NinjectConfigurator` class:

```
public class NinjectConfigurator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Entry method used by caller to configure the given 
    /// container with all of this application's 
    /// dependencies. Also configures the container as this
    /// application's dependency resolver.
    /// </summary>
    public void Configure(IKernel container)
    {
        // Add all bindings/dependencies
        AddBindings(container);

        // Use the container and our NinjectDependencyResolver as
        // application's resolver
        var resolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(container);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add all bindings/dependencies to the container
    /// </summary>
    private void AddBindings(IKernel container)
    {
        ConfigureLog4net(container);

        // Context.
        container.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<TRZFDbContext>().InRequestScope();

        // Repositories.
        container.Bind<IGenericRepository<Aggregation>>().To<GenericRepository<Aggregation>>();

        [ ... ]
    }
}
```

My problem is with the GenericRepository's constructor and the implementation of the Unit of Work pattern:

```
public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    _context = (DbContext)unitOfWork;
    _dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
}
```

I do it this way because I want to implement `IGenericRepository` without any dependencies, and I thought, maybe I'm wrong, that I have to isolate it from `DbContext` (because I'm going to use another ORM Framework).

I have found another implementations like this one:

```
public class EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I've found it in the article: [Repository pattern, done right](http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/repository-pattern-done-right/).

If the current advice is not to use Repository and Unit of Work patterns, how can I use Entity Framework with dependency injection?

Comment: That's a very old article you're reading from. The current advice is not to use repository/UoW pattern with Entity Framework as it's already it's own repository pattern so you're just adding another pointless layer of abstraction.

Comment: Use EF UOW patter, refer this article https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/a-better-entity-framework-unit-of-work-pattern-DD

Comment: @DavidG Ok, now I know what do I not to do and I still doesn't know what to do. How can I use Entity Framework without repository pattern?

Comment: That's a massively broad question, off topic for SO.

Comment: @DavidG *how can I use Entity Framework with dependency injection?* is a massively broad question?

Comment: @DavidG I've also seen a lot of advice that say not to use repository/UoW pattern with Entity Framework but I've seen many articles that say that you should always have a design where there's an abstraction to any framework (EF in this case). Should there always be a direct dependency to DbConext and EF throughout your code? IMO repository/UoW pattern is still very useful as EF should be interchangeable without other parts of your code ever having to be touched. I think it's a case where an abstraction of an abstraction is still needed.

Comment: @ODawgG You're talking about a service layer that sits between the data and the business layer and I'd never say to remove that. The DbContext needs to stay isolated for sure.